# F-Curve modifier is disabled

Tags: graph-editor

I'm not sure if it is just some simple mute button or what, but I can't figure out how to enable the cycles modifier.

[image]

Comment: have you disabled them? take a look into the tracks on the left, wrench icon

Comment: if that doesn't help...please provide your blend file